# ASP.NET web pages without aspx file extension

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, url-routing

What is best solution to serve ASP.NET web pages without aspx extension? I want to make http://www.mydomain.com/mypage instead of http://www.mydomain.com/mypage.aspx

I use .NET 2.0 and IIS6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can upgrade to .Net 4.0,which got a built-in URL Routing feature to do it for you easily,read [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020111718/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/012710-1.aspx) article by Scott Mitchel

otherwise if you don't want to move to .net 4.0,read [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx) article by Scott Gu

Comment: You should also be able to use MVC's Url Routing capabilities from a WebForms application, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd347546.aspx for example

Answer (score 1):

**Url rewriting**.

For .NET there are already modules available like [this one](http://www.urlrewriting.net/149/en/home.html).

Answer (score 0):

For IIS 6.0 you can use ionics ISAPI URL Rewrite filter http://iirf.codeplex.com/ for extention less urls