# Ho to access page without page extension .aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have hosted a website using c# asp.net

[The page can be found here](http://www.dailycashback.in/sample.aspx)

How do I access the page without the extension **.aspx** like this: http://www.dailycashback.in/sample

When we open the link without the extension, it redirects to a **404** error page

Comment: Duplicate question, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546654/asp-net-web-pages-without-aspx-file-extension) for reference

Comment: ASP.NET MVC web applications do *not* display the `.aspx` suffix. You should probably use MVC instead of Web Forms for new projects

Comment: @R.jauch not a duplicate, ASP.NET has changed a **lot** since 2010. Even Web Forms has routing now. Rewriting is no longer necessary

Answer (score 4):

Add to Your project file `Global.asax`. You need only add routing like this.

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("sample", "sample", "~/sites/sample.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [IIS url rewriter](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) and Web.Config. It will allow you to request every page without the .aspx extension.

```
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>       
        <rule name="no-aspx-extension" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^([a-z0-9/]+)$" ignoreCase="true"/>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.aspx"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```